# Plot a perpendicular line at the edges of a line - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I plot a half of perpendicular line (Total length 10) above and half below the edges (beginning and end) of a line? So, it will look like a rotated error bar.

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
 
x1 =0;
y1 = 10;
x2 = 2;
y2 = 15;
 
lineLength = 10;
 
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
perpSlope = -1/m
 
plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the vector of the direction `dir` of your line, rotate it by 90° `orthDir` and then add/subtract this orthogonal line to your line endpoints.

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
 
x1 =0;
y1 = 10;
x2 = 2;
y2 = 15;

p1 = [x1;y1];
p2 = [x2;y2];
 
plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2]);

lineLength = 10; 
dir = [x1-x2;y1-y2];
dirNormalized = dir./norm(dir);

orthDir = [0,-1;1,0]*dirNormalized;

hold on;
plot([p1(1), p1(1)+orthDir(1)*5],[p1(2), p1(2)+orthDir(2)*5],'g-')
plot([p1(1), p1(1)-orthDir(1)*5],[p1(2), p1(2)-orthDir(2)*5],'g-')
plot([p2(1), p2(1)+orthDir(1)*5],[p2(2), p2(2)+orthDir(2)*5],'g-')
plot([p2(1), p2(1)-orthDir(1)*5],[p2(2), p2(2)-orthDir(2)*5],'g-')
axis equal
```

[image]